# Php array_merge is not working properly together with array_intersect_key on Numerical keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have a strange scenario that Array_merge is working on non_numbers Keys but it wont work on number keys even I try to use "Add" instead of Array_merge.

***The coding***

```
$array_1['key1']="";
$array_1['key2']="";
$array_1['key3']="";
$array_1['key4']="";
$array_1['key5']="";
$array_1['key6']="";
$array_1['key7']="";

$array_2['key1']="value1";
$array_2['key3']="value2";
$array_2['key4']="value3";
$array_2['key8']="value4";

$array_3[1]="";
$array_3[2]="";
$array_3[3]="";
$array_3[4]="";
$array_3[5]="";
$array_3[6]="";
$array_3[7]=""; 

$array_4[1]="1";
$array_4[3]="2";
$array_4[4]="3";
$array_4[8]="4";

$results= array_merge($array_1, array_intersect_key($array_2, $array_1));
echo '<pre>',print_r($results),'</pre>';

$results2= array_merge($array_3, array_intersect_key($array_4, $array_3));
echo '<pre>',print_r($results2),'</pre>';
```

[image]

I thought by using the + operator will be working, but its not.

```
$results2= $array_3+array_intersect_key($array_4, $array_3);
```

instead of

```
$results2= array_merge($array_3, array_intersect_key($array_4, $array_3));
```

The output is left side which is wrong; all the values in $array_4 has gone!  I want the results to be the right side.

[image]

Anyone can help?

Comment: array_merge and + work as documented. It looks like you want array_replace.

Comment: @jh1711 plz be more specific for what you have mentioned "array_replace"

Comment: https://3v4l.org/XKZrl. I'm not sure what else to say. Array_replace does what you want with numeric indexes. Array_merge does not.

Comment: If you read the manual this is answered FYI http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php look for "Don't forget that numeric keys will be renumbered!" So works for strings not for numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) works as it is explained in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value **will not** overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

There are three ways to combine two arrays.

#### `array_merge()`

[`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) works differently for string and numeric keys.

The returned array contains all the string keys from both arrays. For common keys, the values from the second array are returned.

All the values associated with numeric keys are returned in the resulting array. Those from the first array are first then those from the second array. The numeric keys are not preserved, they start from zero in the returned array.

Example:

```
$array1 = array(
    'one' => 1,
    2 => 2,
    'three' => 3,
    4 => 4,
);

$array2 = array(
    'three' => 'three',
    4 => 'four',
    5 => 'five',
    'six' => 'six'
);

print_r(array_merge($array1, $array2));
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [one] => 1
    [0] => 2
    [three] => three
    [1] => 4
    [2] => four
    [3] => five
    [six] => six
)
```

#### `$array1 + $array2`

The [union operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)
generates an array that contains all the keys and values of the first array and the keys of the second array (with the corresponding values) that are not present in the first array. It handles both string and numeric keys the same way and it doesn't re-index.

When a key is present in both arrays, the value from the first array is used. The one from the second array is ignored.

The output of `print_r($array1 + $array2)`:

```
Array
(
    [one] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [three] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => five
    [six] => six
)
```

#### `array_replace()`

[`array_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) also handles the string and numeric keys the same way. The array it returns contains all the keys from both arrays. For common keys, the values from the second array are returned.

The output of `print_r(array_replace($array1, $array2))` is:

```
Array
(
    [one] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [three] => three
    [4] => four
    [5] => five
    [six] => six
)
```

Apart from the order of the keys and values, `array_replace($array1, $array2)` return the same array as `$array2 + $array1`.

#### Conclusion

If you want to merge two arrays, use `$array1 + $array2` if the values of `$array1` are more important or `array_replace($array1, $array2)` if the values of `$array2` are more important. In both cases, the keys of `$array1` come first in the resulting array, then the keys of `$array2` that are not present in `$array1`.

`array_merge()` works fine when the arrays it merges has the same type of keys (either all numeric or all strings). If the keys are strings, `array_merge($array1, $array2)` produces the same result as `array_replace($array1, $array2)`.

If all keys are numeric, `array_merge($array1, $array2)` produces an array that contains all the values of `$array1` followed by all values of `$array2` (each set in the same order it was in the original array). The keys in the new array are numeric, consecutive and start from zero.

For numeric keys, `array_merge($array1, $array2)` produces the same result as:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array1 as $value) {
    $result[] = $value;
}
foreach ($array2 as $value) {
    $result[] = $value;
}
```

All these three methods can be used to combine more than two arrays. The result when they combine more than two arrays is the same result they produce when they combine the first two arrays then the result with the third and so on, from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

> Try replace the second **array_merge with array_replace**

```
$results2= array_replace($array_3, array_intersect_key($array_4, $array_3));
```